# Issue displaying local image files via css class and/or img src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have some issues rising up displaying Image files from local filesystem.
And to say it before: yes i am aware of the security breach this is causing and there is no other way playing it different because my company has no file Server yet to serve these images in a proper way.

With that out of the way the scenario:

I have an angular app which should show me some Images on my page. I wrote a directive called Gallery to do so. 
Into this gallery I am handing in the absolute paths to my Image files and just set the src attribute via javascript. I tested it with some random chosen files picked from Google and everything worked out well. Allthough my browser is throwing out error because of security the picutres were displayed.

But when i got the real data from my company collegue Things started getting nasty. The error still thrown in console but nothing was displayed. I checked first overwriting the img.onload listener finding out that the testimages are giving me the Output i put onto the listener, my real data images didn't.

Next I tried to set the background attribute and not the src one. My test images were displayed the real data ONLY if it is placed into the assets folder of my app. This got me quite confused because like mentioned above using my test images it doesn't matter where they are placed, they are displayed everytime.

I also tried changing file format from png to jpg but nothing happens.
Also scaling down the images (real data has big px solutions) didn't work either.

So my question is simple ...what am i doing wrong? Could it be possible that those real data images are not exported properly. But if that's the case, why do they work in the assets folder? Like mentioned security block is not possible because my test pictures a doing well.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: As you said in the beginning: It won't work with images from the file system. Even if your company really needs it.

Comment: Repeating for effect -- you cannot show images from the local filesystem like that. They have to go where the web server can serve them.

Comment: ty for your commets so far but it is working ... you can also still open a Directory using file://// protocol and to repeat it again i know that it is bad style overall but this should not be the point beeing discussed here. My Code is rly simple ... from my Controller i just call $scope.image.src = <path>. It is working for $scope.image.scr="C:/foo.jpg" but not for $scope.image.src="C:/real_data.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the bug which was responsible for the behaviour ... It was no wrong linking it was the IIS Express which was caching old links. @mrunion and @cloned links to filesystem are still working on IE and also in Edge just for devs which have no other choice then to do it that way

Cheers Max